# LOVOO like radar view in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have trying to achieve the exact radar view like LOVOO application in android & iOS, but with no luck. I found a [ios LOVOO like radar view](https://github.com/abm-adnan/Radar), but not for android.

[image]

Can anyone please help me in this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one sample on github which will help you.
[RadarView](https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar/wiki/radar-plugin)